# Underclocking graphics card in a Linux Server

Tags: linux, graphics-card, power-management

I recently built myself a new Linux Server with a Core 2 Duo 1,83 GHz CPU and a nVidia GeForce 7200LE graphics card, which was the cheapest passively cooled card I could find. I've measured power draw of the system and it seems to draw about 95 Watts.

The graphics card seems to generate quite a bit of heat though, I don't even have a monitor, mouse or keyboard connected to the machine so this seems quite unnecessary.

Can I underclock or even power down the graphics card somehow to conserve energy?

**Update:** After removing the graphics card and undervolting the CPU from 1.25V to 1.1V (seems stable), power usage has dropped to 70 Watts. Thanks everyone.

Comment: shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Answer (score 7):

There is a tool called [nvclock](http://www.linuxhardware.org/nvclock/) which can adjust the clock for Nvidia cards.

It only works if you use the proprietary nvidia driver.

There is a debian/ubuntu package called `nvclock` and GUIs for KDE `nvclock-qt` and GNOME `nvclock-gtk`.

Comment: The server does not have x installed as I'm not intending to use it for any such purpose, do I still need to install the proprietary nVidia driver somehow?

Comment: nvclock depends only on libc, libx11 and libxext. The description says: "The official binary nVidia drivers are required for accesses other than by root.". So, chances are good, but the only way to find a definitive answer is to give it a try.

Comment: It worked, but it really didn't do much, temperature hardly dropped at all and I saved at most 3-4 Watts of power.

Comment: @weazl: It's a pity, but I guess it was worth a try.